# How to assess uncertainty in a Bayesian analysis?

Tags: bayesian, inference, pymc, extreme-value

I'm building a model to estimate recurrence of flood magnitudes via fitting a [GEV distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) to flow data. The aim of the study is to compare stationary and non stationary models using a Bayesian approach. Just to illustrate the problem, this is how my posterior distribution looks for the stationary case:

[image: Posterior]
c values (shape parameter) vary from -0.5 to 0.5. Beta distribution was set for the priori, so a transformation was needed ([Martins and Stedinger, 2000](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/1999WR900330))

The question is: How do we estimate Credible Intervals via pymc3?
Pymc3 is able to calculate [HPD](https://docs.pymc.io/api/stats.html) but that's where I'm struggling to understand. Since HPD only gives credible intervals for each parameter individually (and to build a distribution we should pick sorted MAP parameters set. In this case, location, scale and shape parameters). How is it right to inform flood magnitudes uncertainty based on HPD? Few exemples that I found that assessed uncertainties with individual CIs are [this blog post by Alex Ioannides](https://alexioannides.com/2019/01/18/stochastic-process-calibration-using-bayesian-inference-probabilistic-programs/) and [this paper using GEV as well](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303977615_The_influence_of_non-stationarity_in_extreme_hydrological_events_on_flood_frequency_estimation).
Also, how can I convert parameters uncertainty to flood magnitudes uncertainty? Just plotting with CIs parameters?

One other way that I thought I could do it was to rank the parameters based on the posterior, similar to what is done in [Think Bayes](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-bayes/) in the two dimensions chapter. Then, get a certain number of "best parameters set" for the parameters and then plot every possible curve like in the [GLM example from pymc3](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-robust.html). Is it wrong?

Comment: Welcome to CV Yan Machado. As I understand, you want to infer on a return level corresponding to a given return period e.g. 100 years. If so, just compute a sample of this return level by applying the GEV quantile to you MCMC iterates.  Then compute the HPD as it is done for a GEV parameter. An alternative is using the *predictive posterior* distribution for the maximum on a new
period of time.

Comment: Are you asking about posterior predictive distribution?